# Get position inside image at run time

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, pixel

I have an Image having the face of an actor, I wanna change that face with my picture.
I took two bitmaps and merge and generate new bitmap via canvas, but my picture position varies on different devices.
Can anyone help me? How can I achieve this so that it can come exactly same for different devices?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Audumbar here is the snippt: http://pastie.org/9249364

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps. Atleast one of the below will help you
1. use different images size and manage in xdpi, hdpi, ldpi etc.,
2. set background border for displaying the merged result.
3. set images background with nine patch image in black or white color. It will show your image with black or white border. And also it will manage the screen image size and border for your image. use www.draw9patch.com for creating nine patch image.